# How to display password in textbox in decrypted format?

Tags: php, cookies, encryption

When user visits login page of website, i am checking for cookie, if cookie is available then in login controls i.e. username and password text box will get populate with the values fetched from cookie.

Now in this case, password value is getting display but in encrypted way.

I want to display the password value in decrypted way.

```
For example:  

**Value of username and password in DATABASE:**
username = 'kalpana';
password = '9ee10d53349b49fda27aec3da519b912'   //actual value=kalpana
```

Now in login page, if cookie available, then values of username & password controls are specified below:

```
username = kalpana
password = 9ee10d53349b49fda27aec3da519b912  (in dots format)
```

but here in password i want to show

```
password = kalpana (in dots format)
```

Can anyone pls tell me how to do this?

Comment: what encryption are you using, it lloks like md5 in that case you can not decrypt it.

Comment: Don't do this. Even if you figured out a way, all someone would have to do is view the html source on a page and they would be able to see the password in non-dot-format. Very insecure.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, not with a hashed string anyway.  Even if you could, it would be an incredibly bad idea.

Most sites with persistent logins use a cookie to identify a previously logged in user and allow them to skip the login process.  Why don't you do that?